Volume and volume mount not showing up in datadog agent
I have a multicluster windows and linux. I have deployed cluster agent on linux and then have the datadog agent deployed on windows because i want to get the logs of my app running on windows.
I have applied volume and volume mount in my app.yaml and also in the datadog agent running on windows, with both applied i see the volume and volume mount in my app but not in datadog agent. Is there something i'm missing?[[[[values file for cluster-agentvalues file for datadog-agent on windows](https://i.sstatic.net/6HHzCmWB.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/mdHnUTSD.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/53yT7eDH.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/65l1tlnB.png)
I did the volume and volume mount in my app and also my agent
